# django malformed array literal:

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-jsonfield

I have a little problem:

I have this model:

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    myField =JSONField()
```

I want to update this field:

```
data={'rda': {'punti': 0, 'rank': 1, 'pos': 'eq'}}
a =myModel()
a.myField=data
a.save()
```

but I have this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/hy0/.conda/envs/ciclods_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
>   line 85, in _execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) psycopg2.DataError: malformed array literal: "{"rda": {"punti": 0, "rank": 1, "pos":
>   "eq"}}"

how can I solve it?

Comment: try json.loads(data)

Comment: i tried it but i get an other error 
typeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

Comment: What versions of Django and Postgres are you running?

Comment: Django 2.1 and postgres 10

Comment: Have you changed `myField` to `JSONField` but not generated/applied any migrations after? Was this a different type before? I suspect the database field is of a different type to the one declared in your model.

Comment: I'm hitting this exact problem myself. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You must need to use PostgreSQL.
I tried so far, it works for me

```
data = {  
    'rda':{  
        'punti':0,
        'rank':1,
        'pos':'eq'
    }
}

test = myModel()
test.myField=data
test.save()
```

Comment: That doesn't matter, in Python `"` and `'` are interchangeable.

Comment: Great. I noticed just now and you also comment.

Comment: He is using postgres though, you can tell by the traceback, plus it's mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of `myModel` in order to store this. E.g. something like:

`myModel.objects.create(myField={'rda': {'punti': 0, 'rank': 1, 'pos': 'eq'}})`

I suspect there's some extra code in there that's not obvious, `data` is a `dict` but then you're calling `save` on it which normally raises an `AttributeError`. Also I'm guessing in your original code `myModel` is not an instance of `myModel` but rather the model itself and so you can't operate against it directly, you need an instance of it that represents the database row.

Once you have an instance of `myModel`, you can do:

```py
a_model = myModel()
a_model.myField = {'rda': {'punti': 0, 'rank': 1, 'pos': 'eq'}}
a_model.save()
```

Just to make this clear in my answer too, you need to ensure the database field matches the one declared in your model, check you have generated migrations and applied them for all your latest changes.

Comment: @marcantoniosofia can you update your question to reflect the full code? As it is at the moment it seems like you operate against the model and not the instance.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue and this post is the only reference I could find to it. I'm not sure what the cause is, but I finally fixed it by removing my migration scripts for a fresh database.

If you're hitting this error, try removing the last few migration scripts, until you find the culprit. Alternatively, you can start fresh like me and it should work again.